# Duplex Federation Binding Configuration not working

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

i am developing a duplex federated wcf service, my federation scenario is working fine but when i tried to make it duplex to an exception is thrown "The incoming policy could not be validated"

i think its issue with my configurations but am still not able to trace out the mistake,

Following are my configuration:

1. For my main service:

   ```
   <bindings>
       <customBinding>
           <binding name='MyServiceBinding'>
               <security authenticationMode='SecureConversation'>
                   <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode='IssuedTokenForCertificate'/>
                   <issuedTokenParameters>
                       <issuerMetadata address='http://localhost:62751/TokenIssuer.svc/mex'/>
                   </issuedTokenParameters>
               </security>
               <compositeDuplex/>
               <oneWay/>
               <httpTransport/>
           </binding>
       </customBinding>
   </bindings>

   <services>
       <service name="MyService.MyService"
                          behaviorConfiguration='MyServiceBehavior'>
           <endpoint address="Response"
                                 binding="customBinding"
                                 bindingConfiguration='MyServiceBinding'
                                 contract="MyService.IMyService" />
           <endpoint address="mex"
                     binding="mexHttpBinding"
                     contract="IMetadataExchange" />

       </service>
   </services>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   ```
2. STS Configurations

and 3. Client Configurations

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
                <binding name='MyServiceBinding'>
                    <security authenticationMode='SecureConversation'>
                        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode='IssuedTokenForCertificate'/>
                        <issuedTokenParameters>
                            <issuer address='http://localhost:62751/TokenIssuer.svc' binding='wsHttpBinding' bindingConfiguration='MyTokenIssuer'/>
                        </issuedTokenParameters>
                    </security>
                    <compositeDuplex/>
                    <oneWay/>
                    <httpTransport/>
                </binding>

        </customBinding>

        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyTokenIssuer">
                <security mode="Message"/>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="GetResponseClientBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <client>
        <endpoint name="WSFederationHttpBinding_IMyService" address="http://localhost:53121/MyService.svc/Response" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding" behaviorConfiguration="GetResponseClientBehavior" contract="IMyService">
            <identity>
                <certificateReference storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="BookStoreService.com"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>        
</system.serviceModel>
```